# How to give multiple objects in json input using jmeter for testing

Tags: json, rest, testing, input, jmeter

I'm trying to give multiple Json object input to jmeter for performance testing. My input body is something like this:

```
{
 "ABC": {
        },
 "XYZ": [
    {
      "PId": 13,
      "CIds": [
       1234
              ]
    },
    {
      "PId": 14,
      "CIds": [
       1234
              ]     
    }
        ]
}
```

What would be best way to give such multiple inputs 1 million times where my PId can range from 1 to 1 million or more?

I have tried simple copy paste input values till 100 or 1000 but I'm trying to figure out a better way to give input for such 1 million records.

Comment: You need milion pid inside 1 requests or milion requests with different pid?

Comment: I need million pid inside 1 request